# Click local URL and execute remotely in RDP session?

Tags: remote-desktop, webex

I'm working from home using RDP. Our unified communication platform is Webex (for chat, audio/video calls, meetings, etc.). I run Webex locally because forwarding camera audio and video resources to my RDP session is terrible. Now, since this is also our chat platform, we share a LOT of internal network resources, wiki pages, etc. on it. Clicking on these links locally, opens them locally. While that works, I'd really prefer to keep work stuff confined to the RDP session.

Does anyone know how to forward a local link-click to a remote RDP session?

I'll anticipate answer number one: I'm not running two instances of Webex. I've tried. It's suboptimal. You have to deal with double notifications, those instances fighting over the phone sign-in, and even if you turn off all notifications for one instance, the settings sync and eventually disable all notifications everywhere. Not the answer I'm looking for.

Something super technical is fine. Even just a suggestion of where to look to write something to catch the local click and forward it. Anything really. Thanks!

Comment: Please give more details: What operating systems? Where are you clicking? etc.

Comment: Both local and remote are Windows 10. Clicking the URL in Webex or a system wide handler. I could work with either.